# speed up distance calculation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

How can I speed up the execution of this line:

```
from geopy import distance

...

df['Km'] = df.apply((lambda row: distance.distance(row['coord_1'],row['coord_2']).km),axis=1)
```

where coord_1 and coord_2 are two large sets of coordinates.

distance.distance is a geopy function (https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/distance.py)

Thanking you up in advance.

--- Update: I found a Cython implementation of the Vincenty formula@ github.com/dmsul/cyvincenty.git. It greatly sped up the performance ---

Comment: You need to vectorize the `distance.distance` function (may be it already is, check the documentation). Is the function your code or came from a third party library?

Comment: If the function is written in python, which it probably is, implementing your own in C might help. Python is horrendously slow at calculating pretty much anything.

Comment: the distance.distance function is from the geopy library

Answer (score 1):

Replaced Geopy with a Cython implementation of the Vincenty formula@ github.com/dmsul/cyvincenty.git.

It greatly sped up the performance.

Thanks @Kilves.  Your comment really put me on the right track.